# checkbox needing two click to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

im trying to make todo app. i have checkboxes on each item and im trying to change the value of checked(iscompleted) to true when i click my checkbox and it does that, but it needs two clicks to do that why is that happening im trying to solve this for very long time now

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ControlPanel } from "./ControlPanel";

export const Input = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState("");
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setNewTodo(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const adding = {
      task: newTodo,
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
      checked: isCompleted
    };
    if (newTodo.length) {
      setTodos(todos.concat(adding));
      setNewTodo("");
    }
  };
  const checkbox = (index) => {
    const check = [...todos];
    check[index].checked = isCompleted
    setIsCompleted(!isCompleted);

    setTodos(check);
    console.log(todos);
  
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={newTodo}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="what needs to be done?"
        />

        <ul>
          {todos &&
            todos.map((todo, index) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <input
                  
                    checked={todo.checked ? true : false}
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={() => checkbox(index)}
                  />
                  <li key={todo.index}>{todo.task}</li>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </ul>
        <ControlPanel todos={todos} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main issue is with this line:

```
check[index].checked = isCompleted
```

`isCompleted` is a component-level state, not a Todo one. Since you want to *toggle* the value of the checkbox based on the Todo item itself, you should do something like:

```
check[index].checked = !check[index].checked
```

And BTW, in this code:

```
todos.map((todo, index) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        checked={todo.checked ? true : false}
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => checkbox(index)}
      />
      <li key={todo.index}>{todo.task}</li>
    </div>
  );
})
```

The `key` prop is not in the right place. It should be the parent element - which is, in this case, the `<div>` element:

```
todos.map((todo, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <input
        checked={todo.checked ? true : false}
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => checkbox(index)}
      />
      <li>{todo.task}</li>
    </div>
  );
})
```